# How to solve Heroku give sprockets error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, bower

When I deploy my app on heroku I am getting this error.
I am using bower install in my app . Is it due to this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's best on stackoverflow to not post screenshots if possible. Rather, copy-paste the error into a code block.

The important part of this is `File not found` and it shows that `chosen/chosen.jquery` is the missing file.

Not sure where the source for this file is supposed to be. If you're using a gem, then perhaps the gem assets aren't being loaded correctly.

Otherwise, if you have access to the `chosen.jquery` source, add it to `app/assets/javascripts/chosen.js` and then add `//= require chosen/chosen.js`

By the way, I changed the file extension to `.js` because `.jquery` is not a valid file extension in this context, as far as I'm aware.